# HERE Map Javascript Api gives InvalidArgumentError

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am using HERE Map Api to display Map. My application uses joomla CMS. I get "InvalidArgumentError" in my browser console.

Here is the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: H.map.DomIcon (Argument #0 No element data) ............................ mapsjs-core.js:43:1074
zh https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:164
<anonymous> https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js line 71 > eval:78
<anonymous> https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:71
<anonymous> https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js:7
```

I just included below HERE map scripts and nothing else,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1526040296" />
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This map is working fine when I use same code in separate HTML file. I doubt joomla js file may getting conflict with HERE Map js script.

Any help related to this is very much appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, you get an error just adding script tags with no code calling our APIs?

Comment: Yes, just added script tags

Comment: Hi raymond, any clue ?
Also i can't share the link.

Comment: Just checked "mootools.js" joomla file is creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This Error is thrown **only** if you try to excecute `H.map.DomIcon()` without DOM element as a parameter. Are you sure you don't call `H.map.DomIcon()` somewhere else within your application?

Comment: No I don't call anywhere in my application

Comment: Could you maybe share the link to your application?